# Java FixedThreadPool with resources per thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, resources, thread-safety, executorservice

This is a pseudocode version of my current working code:

```
public class DataTransformer {
    private final boolean async = true;
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void modifyAsync(Data data) {
        if (async) {
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    modify(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            modify(data);
        }
    }

    // This should actually be a variable inside modify(byte[] data)
    // But I reuse it to avoid reallocation
    // This is no problem in this case
    // Because whether or not async is true, only one thread is used
    private final byte[] temp = new byte[1024];

    private void modify(Data data) {
        // Do work using temp
        data.setReady(true); // Sets a volatile flag
    }
}
```

Please read the comments. But now I want to use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` instead of `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. This is easily possible in my case by moving the field `temp` inside `modify(Data data)`, such that each execution has it's own `temp` array. But that's not what I want to do because i want to reuse the array if possible. Instead I want for each of the 10 threads a `temp` array. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use a `ThreadLocal` or some other pooling mechanism.

Comment: Re, "...But I reuse it to avoid reallocation." Have you _measured_ any performance improvement when re-using the `temp` array instead of allocating a new one for each task? It's normal for a Java program to create large numbers of short-lived objects, and the heap and garbage collector are optimized to deal efficiently with that scenario.

Comment: In this particular case it might be faster without pooling. But I'm also curious about how to implement this basically.

Comment: @stonar96, so are you trying to share data between threads?

Comment: @Pakira no. `temp` is just reused. No data is shared.

Comment: you can declare temp as static or if you want to use different values then use threadlocal

Comment: Yes `ThreadLocal` is probably what I am looking for. `static` is optional in this case. @Savior @Pakira if you post an answer I can accept it. If there are further alternative approaches how to do this please tell me.

Comment: @stonar96, I would appreciate if you accept answer for the people who are taking time to answer your questions as per Stackoverflow policy!

Comment: @Pakira I know, as I have said I would have accepted it, but your answer contains parts which have nothing to do with my question. I didn't have time to properly respond to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As `static` variable is shared between all Threads, so you could declare as static. But if you want to use different values then either use Threadlocal or use different object.

With ThreadLocal you could do :

```
  ThreadLocal<byte[]> value = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new byte[1024]);
```

You could also use object like this:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
class Control {
    public volatile byte[] temp = "Hello World".getBytes();
}
final Control control = new Control();

class T1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String a = Arrays.toString(control.temp);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
class T2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String a = Arrays.toString(control.temp);
        System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
private void test() {
    T1 t1 = new T1();
    T2 t2 = new T2();

    new Thread(t1).start();
    new Thread(t2).start();
}
}
```

Comment: While it's true that `ThreadLocal` solves my question, I think you didn't fully understand what I am asking. I don't try to share any state with the temp array between threads or calls of `modify(Data data)`. Therefore `static` alone is not a solution. Making it static would even cause concurrency issues between different SingleThreadExecutors in the initial example. However making a `static ThreadLocal` is fine. Your second code example just shows how data is shared between threads which don't even include writes to temp. That's not what I am asking about.

Comment: My question is about how to reuse the allocated array but not its content. The whole content of the array from the previous execution is overwritten in `modify(Data data)`. So if your answer was just `/*static optional*/ ThreadLocal<byte[]> value = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new byte[1024]);`, it would be acceptable for me.